# Promise resolving inconsistently on Safari on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, promise, safari

I have code that chains together a number of promises and it seems to work on all platforms I am interested in except Safari on ipad.

I am calling a number of API endpoints and need them to be done sequentially. I have wrapped the jquery `$.get` in a utility that adds a bearer token to the headers.

```
   const get = function(url, callback){
    console.log("callback : " + callback);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(function(idToken) {
                console.log("idtoken block");
                return {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken,
                        'ACTING_ON_BEHALF_OF' : ns.actingAs};
            }).then(function(headers) {
                console.log("header in utils.get : " + headers);
                console.log("url asked for in 'then' before resolve of promise : " + url);
                resolve ($.get({
                    url: url,
                    headers: headers,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: callback,
                    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                        alert(textStatus);
                        alert(errorThrown);
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }));
            });
    });
};
```

I call it like so

```
        utils.get("/api/exerciseconfig/v1/" + exclusionsUrl, function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("exclude url callback returned : " + data.items[0]);

        return data.items[0];
    }).then(function (decoyCategory) {
        console.log("decoyCategory : " + decoyCategory);
        const targetUrl = ns.operation + "/" + ns.stage + "/" + ns.category;
```

This seems to work everywhere except Safari on ipad. The log statement in the callback function never gets called, and if I look at the network tab of the developer tools, the HTTP call never seems to finish

Is there anything I need to be aware of when using Promises on safari on ipad?

Comment: This API just seems like a broken design.  Why would you both return a promise AND pass in a callback that gets called (and only gets called in success, not in error).   Either return a promise and use it exclusively or use only a callback for both error and success (using the promise would be preferred in modern design).

Comment: @jfriend00 : thanks for this comment - it gave me just enough to allow me to fix the problem. I removed the callback and implemented that code in a `.then` and things have started looking a lot better. Promises have _always_ been a weak spot for me ...